# Void pointer arithmetic and dereference

Tags: c, pointers, math

I was looking at a quick sort implementation for generic purpose and one of the parameters of the quick sort function was a `void` pointer, and I saw the ff arithmetics on void pointers, so I was wondering what that actually does and if it's even possible?

```
void _qsort(void *v, int size, int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));

void swap(void *v1, void *v2, int size) {
    char buffer[size];
    memcpy(buffer, v1, size);
    memcpy(v1, v2, size);
    memcpy(v2, buffer, size);
}
```

This part appears in the body of the quick sort defined above:

```
    void *vl = (char *)(v + (left * size));
    void *vr = (char *)(v + (mid * size));
    swap(vl, vr, size);
```

so from above code,

1. How is it possible to do arithmetic on `void` pointer `v`, like `v + (left * size)`?
2. What does `void *vl = (char *)(v + (left * size));` part mean? isn't already casted to `char` pointer, if so why are we assigning it to a `void` pointer?
3. In the `swap` part, what exactly is happening, like are the `vl` and `vr` changing their memory location, value or something else?

Comment: The code as described is incorrect, `+` cannot be used on `v` if `v` is a void pointer. It would improve the question to show the exact code

Answer (score 4):

You assume right: arithmetics on `void` pointers is not defined by the C Standard.

The program you are looking at uses a common compiler extension supported by **gcc**, **clang**, **tcc** and many others, that implements arithmetics on `void` pointers as if they were byte pointers.  With this extension, `v + (left * size)` behaves as

```
    (void *)((char *)v + (left * size))
```

So the declaration `void *vl = (char *)(v + (left * size));` is equivalent to:

```
    void *vl = (char *)((void *)((char *)v + (left * size)));
```

Note that the whole expression is cast implicitly to `(void *)` in C.

This declaration can be simplified as:

```
    void *vl = (char *)v + left * size;
```

This is probably what the programmer meant to write and their mistake went unreported because the compiler allows `void *` arithmetics with exactly the same effect.

Regarding your third question, the `swap` function exchanges the contents of the memory blocks pointed to by `v1` and `v2` using a local variable length array `buffer` of `size` bytes. `qsort` is usually called with a rather small element size, so this approach is OK, but calling `qsort` with an array of very long elements (more than a few megabytes) is allowed and could cause a **stack overflow**.

Here is a safer implementation:

```
void swap(void *v1, void *v2, size_t size) {
    unsigned char *p1 = v1;
    unsigned char *p2 = v2;
    while (size >= 8) {
        char buffer[8];
        memcpy(buffer, p1, sizeof buffer);
        memcpy(p1, p2, sizeof buffer);
        memcpy(p2, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        p1 += sizeof buffer;
        p2 += sizeof buffer;
        size -= sizeof buffer;
    }
    if (size > 0) {
        if (size >= 4) {
            char buffer[4];
            memcpy(buffer, p1, sizeof buffer);
            memcpy(p1, p2, sizeof buffer);
            memcpy(p2, buffer, sizeof buffer);
            p1 += sizeof buffer;
            p2 += sizeof buffer;
            size -= sizeof buffer;
        }
        while (size > 0) {
            unsigned char temp = *p1;
            *p1 = *p2;
            *p2 = temp;
            p1++;
            p2++;
            size--;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note these remarks:

- The standard library function `qsort` has a different prototype:

  ```
    void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
  ```
- Using `int` for sizes and index values is not recommended. `left * size` might overflow for a large array on systems with 64-bit `size_t` and 32-bit `int`: The `_qsort` function assumes that `left * size` and `right * size` are within the range of type `size_t` and at most the size of the array pointed to by `v`, yet this size might exceed `INT_MAX`, causing the `int` multiplication to overflow with undefined behavior. The correct type is `size_t` and a sanity check at the beginning of the function can be used to detect invalid arguments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: fair enough, answer amended.

Comment: Minor: why different types? `p1[0]` and `buffer[0]`?  Perhaps `unsigned char` for both.

Comment: Detail: "Using int for sizes and index values is not recommended and left * size might overflow for a large array on 64-bit systems." is true for `size_t` too, just less likely to overflow.  `64-bit` does not equate to 64-bit `size_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: indeed `left * size` can exceed the range of `size_t` but with defined behavior (modulo `SIZE_MAX+1`). It assumed that `left * size <= SIZE_MAX` as it is an offset into an array object. I amended the answer with a more precise explanation.

Comment: I would say `left, right` are indexes into some allocated memory as used in `_qsort()`, but not `left * size, right * size`, which may exceed `SIZE_MAX`. Yet not much need to  dig more into such things.